Need Help on How to Uninstall .tar.bz2 file in fedora
I installed wingpro-10.0.3.0-linux-x64.tar.bz2 several days ago.
Could you please teach me how to uninstall the application since yum remove or dnf remove don't work on tar.bz2 type file.
Appreciated for your help.

How did you "install" it?

If you installed it with make install as I would normally do with *src.tar.bz2, perhaps makefile has an uninstall parameter so make unistall should do the trick

@StephenHarris When I install it, I used xxx.tar.bz2. I forget how to install it yet.

@admstg thank you. But I am not using make install then.

I followed official support guide and find the installation path is /home/nanohe/wingpro/wingpro10/
And I run as below, it works.
# /home/nanohe/wingpro/wingpro10/wing-uninstall
....
....
Deleting /usr/local/bin/wing10
Deleting /home/nanohe/wingpro/wingpro10/file-list.txt
Files remain in /home/nanohe/wingpro/wingpro10. You may want to remove
them and remove the directory.
Removal of installation successful. Thank you for using Wing Pro.

